# How to select the dictionary with the highest value in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of several dictionaries with the same keys and I would like to select the one with the highest value for a specific key. Values are number, how can i do that?

For example, when the specific key is `a` I would like to select `stats[0]` as 1000 is greater than 10.

```
stats = [{'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}, {'a':10, 'b':200, 'c': 1}]
```

Comment: `max(stats, key=lambda x: x['a'])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `max` with a `key` function that selects `a`:

```
max(stats, key=lambda d: d['a'])
```

Comment: I didn't know `max` had a `key` argument.  I guess it makes sense though, just for this situation.

Comment: shouldnt it be d[key]?

Comment: And if the key is not present in all dictionaries: `max([d for d in stats if 'a' in d], key=lambda d: d['a'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
def select_max (dict, key):
   max = dict[0][key]
   maxElement = dict[0]

   for element in dict:
       if element[key] > max:
           maxElement = element
           max = element[key]

   return maxElement
```

Input:

```
select_max([{'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}, {'a':10, 'b':200, 'c': 1}],'a')
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1000, 'b': 3000, 'c': 100}
```